# Accessing different components of MVVm in Ext JS 5

Tags: javascript, extjs, model-view-controller, mvvm, extjs5

I try to use Ext JS 5. Compare it with the previous one. New ViewController and ModelView has been added. Cannot find all information about in one place:

How to access Ext JS store component inside:

1. ViewController
2. ModelView
3. View
4. Controller (application controller used in Ext JS 4)
5. Outsude Ext JS MVC architecture (getStore)

How to access Ext JS model component inside:

1. ViewController
2. ModelView
3. View
4. Controller (application controller used in Ext JS 4)
5. Outsude Ext JS MVC architecture (something like getModel if exists)

Sencha CMD tool is not used, boostrap.js is not used. If some items are required please let me know.

Comment: The best I could advise is to study [Ext Examples](http://dev.sencha.com/ext/5.1.0/examples/index.html) and also [additional examples on MVVM](http://extjs.eu/ext-examples).

Comment: Start here - http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/